# How to debug an incorrect result in my "guessing number" game?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, while-loop

For some reason "correct answer" is not being printed even when i get the answer right. I am not sure why.

```
import random
y = random.randint(1,6)

start_game = input("Pick a number between 1 and 6")


while start_game != y:
  if start_game  > y:
    print("guess too high")
    start_game = input("Pick a number between 1 and 6")
  elif start_game < y:
    print("guess too Low")
    start_game = input("Pick a number between 1 and 6")
  else:
    print("correct guess")`
```

Comment: `input` returns a `string` not an `int` cast it to an `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go out of your while loop before checking the `if, elif, else` condition.
The first thing you check is the condition of your while loop, exiting it if `y = start_game`. You won't reach the else condition.

Move your print after the while loop, out of it.

Also you need to cast input's return to an int.

This way:

```
    import random
    y = random.randint(1,6)

    start_game = int(input("Pick a number between 1 and 6"))


    while start_game != y:
      if start_game  > y:
        print("guess too high")
        start_game = int(input("Pick a number between 1 and 6"))
      elif start_game < y:
        print("guess too Low")
        start_game = int(input("Pick a number between 1 and 6"))
    print("correct guess")
```

The thing is, it will enter the loop, first checking the loop's condition, then it will check the if statement, BUT, the if, elif, else checks stop as soon as one of the condition is true, that means for example even if `y < start_game`, you'll ask for another input but since you entered an if, the elif and else condition won't be checked leading to the end of the loop, then it goes back to checking the loop's condition etc.

Comment: Just added the int conversion ^^

Comment: @Jed no probs ^^ consider selecting an answer and upvoting both mine and Vinny's for the next readers ^^

Comment: No problem!... Sorry i also had one last question in response to your answer. Once i've changed my code, would it make sense to change the "elif" statement to just an "else" statement?

Comment: @Jed No, because `else` means "everything else" you would also check for `y = start_game` ^^

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks!

Comment: Note that in facts else simply means "if no condition is true, do that", but i tought it would be easyer for you to understand this way ^^ !

Answer (score 1):

As @xoxel answered, the problem is you never get to the `else` clause because when `start_game != y` you break out of the while loop.

You can implement it a little different, and it might be more clear:

```
while True:
  if start_game == y:
    print("correct guess")
    break

  elif start_game  > y:
    print("guess too high")
    start_game = int(input("Pick a number between 1 and 6"))
  elif start_game < y:
    print("guess too Low")
    start_game = int(input("Pick a number between 1 and 6"))
```

This loop will always execute, as its evaluation is `True`. Then it checks if it got the correct guess, and breaks if it does - else it asks the user for another input.